# Using Firebase App Check is not working (debug)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, safetynet, firebase-app-check

I am not able to settle this issue when implementing the new App Check feature from Firebase.

When uploading files to Firebase Storage it fails with an error

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}

I already provided the debug secret just like what is in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android-debug-provider?authuser=0).

The debug apk was installed directly via USB debugging.

**Note:**
I am using a physical device and enabled **Enforce** status on both **Storage** and **Real-time database** and it fails whenever I tried to do transaction like upload and the error above shows.

Comment: The documentation is incomplete ... I am stuck at same issue for almost 2 days and found no solution till now !!!

Comment: @AliYarKhan I just stop immediately when I cannot read any related article and documentation about it as it is very new product

Answer (score 3):

Run the App on Physical device. I was facing the same issue and but when i run the app on a physical device it is gone! Ensure you main run app funtion is like this

This is the code [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers?authuser=0#initialize) have mentioned:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I am using physical device, have you enabled Enforce on Storage and Real-time database as well? You need to enable them to see if it really works completely

Comment: Let me know if you were able to make it work on Storage or Real-time database with `Enforce` status enabled.

Comment: yes ... it worked with enforce status .... please ensure you wrapped your run app function in these ```Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key');
  runApp(MyApp());
}```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a physical device, in my opinion, which is far better to use than an emulator. All you need is SHA 256 key and register your application in the safety net in project settings. To get SHA 256 key, just click on the Gradle tab in the leftmost corner in android studio. Click android folder within your application folder and run signiningReport. It will generate SHA 256 key in the terminal and copy it into the safety net. That's it.

Comment: That's all you need when appcheck is not buggy. I cannot debug today on iOS, getting "App not registered" false responses :( It happens sometimes, very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to update all the Firebase related libraries first and try again. it shall work.