# PlatformException(firebase_storage, location should not be a full URL., {}, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I got a problem when , i try to upload image through firestorage.

this function of upload  :

```
 Future uploadFile() async {
    int i = 1;
    final String fileName = DateTime.now().toString();

    for (var img in _image) {
      setState(() {
        val = i / _image.length;
      });

   
      FirebaseStorage  storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

      Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('gs://face14-5d6e2.appspsot.com').child(fileName);


      File file = File(img.path);

      try {
        await ref.putFile(file);
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }

    }
  }
```

/flutter (13708): [firebase_storage/unknown] location should not be a full URL.
I/flutter (13708): /data/user/0/com.example.face1/cache/image_picker3492941265752856582.jpg
E/flutter (13708): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(firebase_storage, location should not be a full URL., {}, null)
E/flutter (13708): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (13708): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (13708): 
E/flutter (13708):
I/flutter (13708): [firebase_storage/unknown] location should not be a full URL.
I/flutter (13708): /data/user/0/com.example.face1/cache/image_picker1191392770962444186.jpg
E/flutter (13708): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(firebase_storage, location should not be a full URL., {}, null)
E/flutter (13708): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (13708): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
E/flutter (13708): 
E/flutter (13708):
I/flutter (13708): [firebase_storage/unknown] location should not be a full URL.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#references) (and as the error says), you don't need to pass the `gs://domain.tld` part in the ref.

```
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/path/to/filename.txt');
```

This should work fine. Alternatively you can try this:

```
Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref()
                    .child('path')
                    .child('to')
                    .child('filename.txt');
```

Comment: I got this error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13708):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13708): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(13708): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session

Comment: ava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/StorageException(13708): Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}                                                                        I/flutter (13708): [firebase_storage/unauthenticated] User is unauthenticated. Authenticate and try again.

Comment: is there any solution ??

Comment: @MohamedElsayed are you logged in ?

Comment: @MohamedElsayed that seems to be another issue. The original question here seems to be resolved. If it was helpful you can accept it by clicking tick icon so others know it's resolved. For the new issue I'd recommend creating a new question or there is already a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759156/using-firebase-app-check-is-not-working-debug)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code and notify that you didn't follow some instruction to implement flutter and firebase storage.

Please refer this link first
[How to implement cloud storage in flutter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/)

Second, Uploading files in fire storage will take lots of seconds, so you need to give some long latency.

I will give you my code in flutter

```
class ImageUpload extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageUploadState createState() => _ImageUploadState();
}

class _ImageUploadState extends State<ImageUpload> {
  String imageUrl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    return Scaffold(  
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Upload Image', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Container()
   );
  }
}
```

**Function to upload image to Firebase Storage**
Here, we are going to implement a function called `uploadImage` that will contain all the configuration from selecting an image from the gallery to uploading it to Firebase Storage to viewing the image in the Image Placeholder section after upload.

Upload code snippet:

```
uploadImage() async {
    final _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;
    //Check Permissions
    await Permission.photos.request();

    var permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.status;

    if (permissionStatus.isGranted){
      //Select Image
      image = await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      var file = File(image.path);

      if (image != null){
        //Upload to Firebase
        var snapshot = await _firebaseStorage.ref()
        .child('images/imageName')
        .putFile(file).onComplete;
        var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        setState(() {
          imageUrl = downloadUrl;
        });
      } else {
        print('No Image Path Received');
      }
    } else {
      print('Permission not granted. Try Again with permission access');
    }
  }
```

Until next time folks, Happy coding!